# Is there a way to determine status of an issue at the end of a sprint with JIRA Agile REST API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

Is there is a way to determine what the status of an issue for the sprint requested (or at minimum if it was resolved during that sprint)?

I'm using the JIRA Agile REST API to get a listing of issues for a sprint ([see documentation and example here](https://docs.atlassian.com/greenhopper/REST/cloud/#agile/1.0/board/%7BboardId%7D/sprint-getIssuesForSprint)).

It does provide a listing of issues for that sprint, but for sprints that have completed it provides the issues current status (it might have been "In Progress" at the end of sprint 2, but now in sprint 4 it is "Resolved" so it will show resolved even when requesting data from sprint 2).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [/rest/api/2/issue](https://docs.atlassian.com/greenhopper/REST/cloud/#agile/1.0/issue-getIssue) with changelog expansion:

`<JIRA URL>/rest/api/2/issue/<ISSUE KEY>?expand=changelog`

It provides you with the change log of an issue (including both status changes and sprint reassignment). I think that by exploring this information you might be able to get the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like once an item is resolved there is a resolvedate that you can use to determine which sprint the resolution occurred in.  It still doesn't provide a mechanism to determine what state the issue was in when the sprint ended (i.e. what items were not started when the sprint finished), but the resovledate looks to solve most of those issues.